# Unable to connect from my local system to ec2 instance created by terraform script

Tags: terraform, amazon-ec2, aws-vpc, aws-security-group, aws-subnets

Following is the source code:

```
variable "ec2_instance_type_name" {
    type    = string
    default = "t2.nano"
}

terraform {
    required_providers {
        aws = {
            source = "hashicorp/aws"
            version = "~> 3.27"
        }
    }
}

provider "aws" {
    alias   = "us"
    region  = "us-east-1"
}

provider "aws" {
    alias   = "eu"
    region  = "eu-west-1"
}

data "aws_ami" "amazon_2" {
    provider = aws.eu
    most_recent = true

    filter { 
        name = "name"
        values = ["amzn2-ami-kernel-*-hvm-*-x86_64-gp2"]
    } 
    owners = ["amazon"]
}

data "http" "myip" {
    url = "http://ipv4.icanhazip.com"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "docdb_peer" {
    provider                = aws.eu
    cidr_block              = "172.32.0.0/16"
    enable_dns_support      = true
    enable_dns_hostnames    = true
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw_connect" {
    provider = aws.eu
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.docdb_peer.id
}

resource "aws_security_group" "vpc_sg" {
    provider = aws.eu
    vpc_id       = aws_vpc.docdb_peer.id
    name         = "vpc-connect"
    description  = "VPC Connect"
  
    ingress {
        cidr_blocks = ["${chomp(data.http.myip.body)}/32"]
        from_port   = 22
        to_port     = 22
        protocol    = "tcp"
    } 

    egress {
        from_port   = 0
        to_port     = 0
        protocol    = "-1"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
    provider = aws.eu
    vpc_id                    = aws_vpc.docdb_peer.id
    availability_zone         = "eu-west-1a"
    cidr_block                = "172.32.0.0/20"
    map_public_ip_on_launch   = true
}

resource "aws_instance" "tunnel-ec2" { 
    provider = aws.eu
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.vpc_sg.id}"]
    subnet_id     = aws_subnet.main.id
    ami           = data.aws_ami.amazon_2.id
    instance_type = var.ec2_instance_type_name
    key_name      = "ireland_ofc_new"
    depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.gw_connect]
}
```

I try to ssh into the system using the key pair pem file and it just timeout.
My other ec2 instance which I manually created works just fine.
Please help resolve the issue.

Comment: Without seeing how your other instances are configured we can't tell how this differs.  I'll point out that 172.32/20 is a public address space and probably why you can't connect.

Comment: Has your terraform instance been assigned an IP address? Does its security group(s) allow SSH access?

Comment: The default route was missing in the routing table, which was why I was unable to ssh into the ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the default route was missing in the routing table.

```
resource "aws_route" "update" {
    provider               = aws.docdb_peer
    route_table_id         = "${aws_vpc.docdb_peer.default_route_table_id}"
    destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id             = "${aws_internet_gateway.gw_connect.id}"
}
```

Adding this solved the issue.